# Javascript Illegal Invocation on DOMTokenList

Tags: javascript, dom

Today i've a strange error in my javascript function.

At the top of the function i do this check

```
 function someName ( obj ) 
 {
   if ( obj == 'undefined' )
     return false ;

   return true ;
 }
```

This piece of code work fine, but if i pass an instance of DOMTokenList in the obj the function throw an exception (Illegal invocation exception).

Some who can tell me why ?
(there is no ajax or other strange thing, the DOMTokenList is taken from current DOM and in this case from an existing button)

Comment: Why not just `if (!obj)` ?

Comment: I don't know , now i try to see if work, but give the same result of mine check? 
And why this error (the code seem too simple and "linear" to give some exception..) ?

Comment: @Skary, can you post the complete code on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Rikard Seems that is not the same , if obj is an object (!obj) return false , if obj is undefined (!obj) return false too..

Eg : 
var a = new Object () ;

alert ( !a) ;

var b = 'undefined';
alert ( !b) ;

Comment: `obj == 'undefined'` Are you actually passing the string `"undefined"` to the function? If so, why? In any case, you've not provided enough information. The code you have is not directly responsible for the error.

Comment: i've build a test case that seem to reproduce the same error (tested with chorme).
I'm not confident with fiddler so i posted on pastebin :
http://pastebin.com/5mcuLbwZ

Comment: Why are you doing `if (_objectRef == null || _objectRef == 'undefined')` ? Again, why would you expect the `_objectRef` to be the string `"undefined"` ?

Comment: i try to check if the object exist.
Reading on internet i've understand that if an object is udefined then  obj == 'undefined' will be true.
I misunderstood something ? 
Is without quotes the correct code ?